# Using a Tuple as a Key in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, tuples, pysimplegui

I have a table I built with PySimpleGUI and I want the key of an input text box to be an array element. Something like:

```
    import PySimpleGUI as sg
    in1 = 1
    out1 = 2
    rows = 1 #number of rows in table
    layout = [
        [sg.Text('Input1', size =(5, 1)),sg.InputText(size=(7, 1),key=(in1,0))],
        [sg.Text('Output1', size =(5, 1)),sg.Text(size=(7,1),background_color='#e6d4a8', 
        relief='sunken', border_width=1, key=(out1,0))],
        #more rows...
        [sg.Text('')],
        [sg.Button('Start', size=(5, 1)), sg.Exit('Exit', size=(5, 1))]
    ]
    window = sg.Window('Test Window', layout) 

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        for x in range(rows):
            (out1,x) = (in1,x)/2 #but this doesn't work
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
           break      

    window.close()
```

How do I set this up so that I can do an operation on the tuples and the tuple will also work as the layout text box key?

Comment: Use the `values` variable to get the values of the input elements.  `values[(out1,x)]` is the kind of thing you're looking for.  Print out your values variable so you know what's in there for you manipulate.